# Simplest way to match multiple fields of a struct against `None`

Tags: rust

I have a Rust struct like this:

```
pub struct SomeMapping {
    pub id: String,
    pub other_id: Option<String>,
    pub yet_another_id: Option<String>,
    pub very_different_id: Option<String>
}
```

What is the simplest way to check if all optional ids are not set? I know the syntax like

```
if let Some(x) = option_value {...}
```

to extract a value from an `Option`, but I don't get how to use this in a concise way to check multiple values for `None`.

Comment: https://play.integer32.com/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bb1ab402be807c14e01db5ac944465c2

Comment: "check if all optional ids are not set" – I'm not sure I'm parsing this correctly. Do you really want to check for the case that they are _all_ `None`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can destructure a structure in pattern matching like so:

```rust
pub struct SomeMapping {
    pub id: String,
    pub other_id: Option<String>,
    pub yet_another_id: Option<String>,
    pub very_different_id: Option<String>,
}

fn main() {
    let x = SomeMapping {
        id: "R".to_string(),
        other_id: Some("u".to_string()),
        yet_another_id: Some("s".to_string()),
        very_different_id: Some("t".to_string()),
    };

    if let SomeMapping {
        id: a,
        other_id: Some(b),
        yet_another_id: Some(c),
        very_different_id: Some(d),
    } = x {
        println!("{} {} {} {}", a, b, c, d);
    }
}
```

It is documented in the Rust book [chapter 18](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#destructuring-structs).