# How to write multiple condition in if let statement?

Tags: rust

How to modify `if let` statement so it also handles another condition like `Some(7) == b`?

```rust
let a = Some(6);
let b = Some(7);
if let Some(6) = a /* && Some(7) = b */{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can use a simple tuple:

```
if let (Some(6), Some(7)) = (a, b) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if `b` is dependent on `a`.  I was looking for a way around using nested if statements, e.g. `if let Some(c) = a && Some(7) = c`.

Comment: @hackel you can use sigil `@` for that: `if let Some(c @ Some(7)) = a`. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=823237c3223b4c97706857a4c6b0acd9

Comment: Using [`@`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#identifier-patterns), it can be written as `if let Some(c @ 7) = a`.

Answer (score 18):

The [`if let` expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/if-expr.html#if-let-expressions) only admits one match arm pattern against one expression. However, they can be merged together into a single equivalent pattern match condition. In this case, the two `Option` values can be combined into a pair and matched accordingly.

```
if let (Some(6), Some(7)) = (a, b) {
    // do something
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b6b03f7698c51bca9202721b9438376a)

See also:

- [Simplest way to match multiple fields of a struct against `None`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58893899/simplest-way-to-match-multiple-fields-of-a-struct-against-none)